# display popup.html in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Can anyone help me with chrome `page_action`? Someone told me that after I've declared it inside the `manifest.json` file, I need to enable it. I've read the docs and saw the code examples but it's not clear how I can show my `popup.html` file when the icon is not grayed out.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to show a popup in your extension you need:

- A `popup.html` (you can use the name that you prefer) file.
- Define popup file in your `manifest.json` as you can see in the next example:

```
"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": {
    "48": "icon.png",
    "128": ".png"
   },
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
```

Also, you need to ensure that you are using the correct format for the version of the manifest of your extension.

[The last version of the manifest is v2](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion). Check what is the version declared in your manifest and check if it has the correct format according with the [official documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest)